# How to add a second local loop_back address?

Tags: linux, networking

I already have a loopback address at 127.0.0.1, which corresponds to a host in the local loopback network 127.0.0.0/8. How could I create a second local loopback host with an address of 127.0.0.2? Does anyone knows the exact command?

Comment: It will already respond to everything in the network 127/8, so it would already respond to `127.0.0.2` without any additional configuration

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1) Can add it temporary using below command

```
ifconfig lo:40 192.168.40.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

2) Add them permanently to /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo lo:10 lo:20
iface lo inet loopback

iface lo:10 inet static
        address 192.168.10.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.10.0

iface lo:20 inet static
        address 192.168.20.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.20.0
```

Comment: The OP has since added they are using Linux, but either way, please don't post link only answers. The site is to be used as a knowledge base, so by all means credit the link, but also be sure post the details relevant to resolving the users question as the link could change or disappear at any time :)

Comment: It was edited after I post my answer. Anyway, here is the detailed steps.

Comment: So, what about the loopback? Is not possible to add 127.0.0.2 ? Also, could you explain `lo:10` and `lo:20`

Comment: It was an example, you can configure it with any loopback IP.  lo:10 is a subinterface name. You can put any number there instead of 10

Comment: Be careful with the netmask on loopback, it will actually respond to an address in the network on it, so in your example `lo` would also respond to 192.168.40.2, 192.168.40.3, ..., better to use `/32` netmasks for loopback most of the time

Answer (score 18):

Though it's probably not actually leaving us soon, `ifconfig` is the "old" way of doing things, and is being replaced with the `ip` command.  The way to do this with `ip` is:

```
ip addr add 192.168.40.1/32 dev lo
```

There's no need for virtual interfaces any more (i.e., the `lo:10` and so forth Mukesh used), but you can still have them if you want like

```
ip addr add 192.168.40.1/32 dev lo label lo:40
```

note that I'm using `/32` netmasks because `lo` is special in that it will answer for an address belonging to a network configured on it.  So if you add `192.168.40.1/24` it will actually respond to any `192.168.40.*` address, not just `.1`

To that end, for your original example of `127.0.0.2`, it will actually already respond to that, because it falls in `127.0.0.0/8` so you don't have to do anything at all to get that particular address.

Also, be careful with addresses on loopback, because the kernel will know that address is on the host and will reply to requests for that address on physical interfaces as well.

Comment: does anyone have a clue on how to make this permanent on ubuntu 18.04 (using netplan or whatever)?

Comment: @kmpm that would be better as a new question.  If it gets answered in the comments here it's tougher for other people to find it later when they also need to know how to do it.  You could ask that here or you could try the Ubuntu specific SE site

Comment: @Dirk as I said above, that would be better as a new question if there isn't one already, and when you ask, be sure to include information about the OS you're using as the answer will vary depending on the platform.

Answer (score 1):

Tested on my Raspberry Pi which is Raspbian, Debian based, so this should work as well on Debian. I created `/etc/network/interfaces.d/lo` with the following contents:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface lo inet static
    address 127.0.0.2/24
    broadcast 0.0.0.0
```

On Debian you should already have the first two lines in `/etc/network/interfaces`, so you can **add the remaining lines there**. On Raspbian it seemed the first two lines were implicit and not needed, but it worked with them too.

NB: To use the `interfaces.d` directory you will have to add the following to `/etc/network/interfaces` if not already there:

```
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

Answer (score 0):

For me `lo:` didn't worked but `lo` worked in Ubuntu. What I did was

```
sudo ifconfig lo 127.0.0.2 netmask 255.0.0.0 up
sudo ifconfig lo 127.0.0.3 netmask 255.0.0.0 up
```

And then hitting `ifconfig` -a will fetch the details.

Comment: Please also read the second answer, which uses the newer `ip` instead of `ifconfig`. It's shorter, too.