# socat sending from the wrong IP address

Tags: linux, networking, socat

I am using socat to forward UDP traffic from one port to another with the following command:

```
socat -T5 UDP4-LISTEN:12345,reuseaddr,fork UDP4:127.0.0.1:23456,bind=127.0.0.2,so-bindtodevice=lo
```

Using netcat to test this, I ran `nc -u -l -p 23456 -vv` and `echo test | nc -u 127.0.0.1 12345`. This gave me the following unexpected output:

```
listening on [any] 23456 ...
connect to [<myPublicIp>] from <hostname> [<myPublicIp>] 53995
test
```

Instead of seeing `<myPublicIp>` as the source address, I would have expected to see `127.0.0.2`. Am I misunderstanding something about networking, or am I using socat incorrectly?

The affected server is running Debian 10, Linux kernel version is 4.19.0-13-amd64, socat version is 1.7.3.2.

**EDIT:**
When using TCP, the output is slightly different:

```
listening on [any] 23456 ...
connect to [127.0.0.1] from <hostname> [<myPublicIp>] 48520
test
```

As requested, the relevant output of `netstat -aun`

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State  
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:12345           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 <myPublicIp>:23456      <myPublicIp>:54299      ESTABLISHED
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33156         127.0.0.1:12345         ESTABLISHED
```

**EDIT 2**:
I can confirm that it doesn't happen on a fresh Debian install. Additionally, I've tried a few other things:

Creating another interface using [tunctl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375799/how-can-i-create-an-additional-lo-interface), and making socat use that interface. The commands executed are:

1. `tunctl`
2. `ifconfig tap1 192.168.10.1 netmask 255.255.255.255 up`
3. `socat -T5 UDP4-LISTEN:12345,reuseaddr,fork UDP4:127.0.0.1:23456,bind=192.168.10.1,so-bindtodevice=tap1`

The behavior I observed is exactly as the UDP example above; all requests appear to originate from `<myPublicIp>`.

Additionally, I tried using [this approach](https://superuser.com/questions/1089092/how-to-add-a-second-local-loop-back-address) to create more loopback addresses.

1. `ifconfig lo:10 192.168.10.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up`
2. `socat -T5 UDP4-LISTEN:12345,reuseaddr,fork UDP4:127.0.0.1:23456,bind=192.168.10.1`

This actually worked, requests seem to originate from `192.168.10.1`. Using

```
socat -T5 UDP4-LISTEN:12345,reuseaddr,fork UDP4:127.0.0.1:23456,bind=192.168.10.2
```

(different bind address) doesn't work, requests now originate from `192.168.10.1`.

Creating multiple aliases for `lo` doesn't work either.

1. `ifconfig lo:1 192.168.10.1 netmask 255.255.255.255 up`
2. `ifconfig lo:2 192.168.10.2 netmask 255.255.255.255 up`
3. `ifconfig lo:3 192.168.10.3 netmask 255.255.255.255 up`

Trying to use either of these interfaces results in all requests coming from the first of these that was created. In this case, `192.168.10.1`. Removing `lo:1` would then make all requests come from `192.168.10.2`. After readding `lo:1`, requests would still come from `192.168.10.2`, as right now, `lo:2` is the "oldest" interface alias.

**EDIT 3:**
Firewall rules (as requested). `enp35s0` is my public interface.

```
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Fri Jul 23 12:15:33 2021
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
-A INPUT -i enp35s0 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 1195 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp35s0 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 1195 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp35s0 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 1195 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp35s0 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 1195 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp35s0 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 1195 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-d83e4273341d -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-d83e4273341d -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-d83e4273341d ! -o br-d83e4273341d -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-d83e4273341d -o br-d83e4273341d -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-adf3fed056db -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-adf3fed056db -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-adf3fed056db ! -o br-adf3fed056db -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-adf3fed056db -o br-adf3fed056db -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp35s0 -o tun+ -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp35s0 -o tun+ -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp35s0 -o tun+ -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp35s0 -o tun+ -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -o enp35s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp35s0 -o tun+ -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.4/32 ! -i br-adf3fed056db -o br-adf3fed056db -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8048 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.4/32 ! -i br-adf3fed056db -o br-adf3fed056db -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8008 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.5/32 ! -i br-adf3fed056db -o br-adf3fed056db -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9005 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.8/32 ! -i br-adf3fed056db -o br-adf3fed056db -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.10/32 ! -i br-adf3fed056db -o br-adf3fed056db -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.11/32 ! -i br-adf3fed056db -o br-adf3fed056db -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8090 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-d83e4273341d -o br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49172 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-d83e4273341d -o br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49171 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-d83e4273341d -o br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49170 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-d83e4273341d -o br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49169 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-d83e4273341d -o br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49168 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-d83e4273341d -o br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49167 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-d83e4273341d -o br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49166 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-d83e4273341d -o br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49165 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-d83e4273341d -o br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49164 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-d83e4273341d -o br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49163 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-d83e4273341d -o br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49162 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-d83e4273341d -o br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49161 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-d83e4273341d -o br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49160 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-d83e4273341d -o br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49159 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-d83e4273341d -o br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49158 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-d83e4273341d -o br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49157 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-d83e4273341d -o br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49156 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-d83e4273341d -o br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49155 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-d83e4273341d -o br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49154 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-d83e4273341d -o br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49153 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-d83e4273341d -o br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49152 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-d83e4273341d -o br-d83e4273341d -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5349 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-d83e4273341d -o br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 5349 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-d83e4273341d -o br-d83e4273341d -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3478 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-d83e4273341d -o br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 3478 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-d83e4273341d ! -o br-d83e4273341d -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-adf3fed056db ! -o br-adf3fed056db -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-d83e4273341d -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-adf3fed056db -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Jul 23 12:15:33 2021
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Fri Jul 23 12:15:33 2021
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 12348 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.9.0.11:62128
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 12348 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.9.0.11:62128
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 12348 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.9.0.11:62128
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 12348 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.9.0.11:62128
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.0/16 ! -o br-d83e4273341d -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.0/16 ! -o br-adf3fed056db -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o enp35s0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.9.0.0/24 -o enp35s0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o enp35s0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.9.0.0/24 -o enp35s0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.4/32 -d 172.18.0.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8048 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.4/32 -d 172.18.0.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8008 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.5/32 -d 172.18.0.5/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9005 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.8/32 -d 172.18.0.8/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.10/32 -d 172.18.0.10/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.11/32 -d 172.18.0.11/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8090 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 49172 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 49171 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 49170 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 49169 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 49168 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 49167 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 49166 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 49165 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 49164 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 49163 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 49162 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 49161 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 49160 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 49159 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 49158 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 49157 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 49156 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 49155 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 49154 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 49153 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 49152 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5349 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5349 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3478 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 3478 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o enp35s0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.9.0.0/24 -o enp35s0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o enp35s0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.9.0.0/24 -o enp35s0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o enp35s0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.9.0.0/24 -o enp35s0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -i br-d83e4273341d -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -i br-adf3fed056db -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -d 127.0.0.1/32 ! -i br-adf3fed056db -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8048 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.4:8048
-A DOCKER -d 127.0.0.1/32 ! -i br-adf3fed056db -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8008 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.4:8008
-A DOCKER -d 127.0.0.1/32 ! -i br-adf3fed056db -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9005 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.5:9005
-A DOCKER -d 127.0.0.1/32 ! -i br-adf3fed056db -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9006 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.8:8080
-A DOCKER -d 127.0.0.1/32 ! -i br-adf3fed056db -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8765 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.10:8080
-A DOCKER -d 127.0.0.1/32 ! -i br-adf3fed056db -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8090 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.11:8090
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49172 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:49172
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49171 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:49171
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49170 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:49170
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49169 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:49169
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49168 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:49168
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49167 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:49167
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49166 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:49166
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49165 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:49165
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49164 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:49164
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49163 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:49163
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49162 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:49162
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49161 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:49161
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49160 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:49160
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49159 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:49159
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49158 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:49158
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49157 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:49157
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49156 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:49156
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49155 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:49155
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49154 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:49154
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49153 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:49153
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 49152 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:49152
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d83e4273341d -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5349 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:5349
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 5349 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:5349
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d83e4273341d -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3478 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:3478
-A DOCKER ! -i br-d83e4273341d -p udp -m udp --dport 3478 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:3478
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Jul 23 12:15:33 2021
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Fri Jul 23 12:15:33 2021
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Jul 23 12:15:33 2021
```

Output of `ip a`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp35s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:a1:59:48:f5:da brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet <myPublicIPv4>/26 brd 135.181.209.63 scope global enp35s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 <myPublicIPv6>/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::aaa1:59ff:fe48:f5da/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:f4:2e:c5:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:f4ff:fe2e:c595/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: br-adf3fed056db: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:4b:fd:ae:6f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-adf3fed056db
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:4bff:fefd:ae6f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
216865: veth225712d@if216864: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-d83e4273341d state UP group default 
    link/ether 32:65:78:a0:be:47 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 10
    inet6 fe80::3065:78ff:fea0:be47/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
61: br-d83e4273341d: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:c4:38:c9:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.19.0.1/16 brd 172.19.255.255 scope global br-d83e4273341d
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:c4ff:fe38:c9c5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
202134: tap0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/ether 36:e7:1a:1f:b5:c8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.9.0.1/24 brd 10.9.0.255 scope global tap0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::34e7:1aff:fe1f:b5c8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
202135: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.8.0.1 peer 10.8.0.2/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::cc13:3dec:ab8c:2e3b/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
88033: veth0949050@if88032: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-adf3fed056db state UP group default 
    link/ether 1e:e0:14:92:f3:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::1ce0:14ff:fe92:f3ad/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
88035: veth5621bc2@if88034: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-adf3fed056db state UP group default 
    link/ether 66:a7:77:bd:d0:ca brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::64a7:77ff:febd:d0ca/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
88037: veth00b963e@if88036: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-adf3fed056db state UP group default 
    link/ether e6:18:ec:30:5c:a6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 3
    inet6 fe80::e418:ecff:fe30:5ca6/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
88041: vethda3acd6@if88040: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-adf3fed056db state UP group default 
    link/ether 3a:ad:d7:6c:fa:cb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 4
    inet6 fe80::38ad:d7ff:fe6c:facb/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
88043: veth2f937b7@if88042: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-adf3fed056db state UP group default 
    link/ether ea:9e:65:d9:9a:f3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 5
    inet6 fe80::e89e:65ff:fed9:9af3/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
88045: vethac132e2@if88044: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-adf3fed056db state UP group default 
    link/ether e2:46:7e:4f:71:52 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 6
    inet6 fe80::e046:7eff:fe4f:7152/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
88049: vethe8f0958@if88048: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-adf3fed056db state UP group default 
    link/ether 9a:e9:40:f1:4d:6b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 7
    inet6 fe80::98e9:40ff:fef1:4d6b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
88053: vethf57e351@if88052: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-adf3fed056db state UP group default 
    link/ether 6a:52:e2:51:c5:7d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 2
    inet6 fe80::6852:e2ff:fe51:c57d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
88055: vethec5ddd0@if88054: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-adf3fed056db state UP group default 
    link/ether 76:69:ec:ce:e7:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 8
    inet6 fe80::7469:ecff:fece:e7f8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
88057: veth473fda8@if88056: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-adf3fed056db state UP group default 
    link/ether 36:48:f4:47:26:81 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 9
    inet6 fe80::3448:f4ff:fe47:2681/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**EDIT 4:**

Output based on Trolzen's answer

```
# socat -d -d UDP-RECVFROM:23456,fork -2021/08/12 12:12:07 socat[4506] N receiving on AF=2 0.0.0.0:23456
2021/08/12 12:12:11 socat[4506] N receiving packet from AF=2 <myPublicIp>:47228
2021/08/12 12:12:11 socat[4506] N forked off child process 4510
2021/08/12 12:12:11 socat[4510] N reading from and writing to stdio
2021/08/12 12:12:11 socat[4510] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [5,5] and [0,1]
2021/08/12 12:12:11 socat[4510] N received packet with 5 bytes from AF=2 <myPublicIp>:47228
test
2021/08/12 12:12:11 socat[4510] N socket 1 (fd 5) is at EOF
2021/08/12 12:12:11 socat[4506] N receiving on AF=2 0.0.0.0:23456
2021/08/12 12:12:12 socat[4510] N exiting with status 0
2021/08/12 12:12:12 socat[4506] N receiving on AF=2 0.0.0.0:23456

# socat -d -d -T.5 UDP-LISTEN:23456,fork -
2021/08/12 12:15:20 socat[4811] N listening on UDP AF=2 0.0.0.0:23456
2021/08/12 12:15:23 socat[4811] N accepting UDP connection from AF=2 <myPublicIp>:55887
2021/08/12 12:15:23 socat[4811] N forked off child process 4817
2021/08/12 12:15:23 socat[4811] N listening on UDP AF=2 0.0.0.0:23456
2021/08/12 12:15:23 socat[4817] N reading from and writing to stdio
2021/08/12 12:15:23 socat[4817] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [5,5] and [0,1]
test
2021/08/12 12:15:23 socat[4817] N inactivity timeout triggered
2021/08/12 12:15:23 socat[4817] N exiting with status 0
2021/08/12 12:15:23 socat[4811] N childdied(): handling signal 17

# socat -d -d UDP-RECV:23456 -
2021/08/12 12:16:12 socat[4891] N reading from and writing to stdio
2021/08/12 12:16:12 socat[4891] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [5,5] and [0,1]
2021/08/12 12:16:15 socat[4891] N received packet with 5 bytes from AF=2 <myPublicIp>:42481
test
```

Output of the "Main command"

```
2021/08/12 12:22:37 socat[5435] N accepting UDP connection from AF=2 <myPublicIp>:40659
2021/08/12 12:22:37 socat[5435] N forked off child process 5482
2021/08/12 12:22:37 socat[5435] N listening on UDP AF=2 0.0.0.0:12345
2021/08/12 12:22:37 socat[5482] N opening connection to AF=2 127.0.0.1:23456
2021/08/12 12:22:37 socat[5482] N successfully connected from local address AF=2 127.0.0.2:36305
2021/08/12 12:22:37 socat[5482] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [5,5] and [6,6]
2021/08/12 12:22:42 socat[5482] N inactivity timeout triggered
2021/08/12 12:22:42 socat[5482] N exiting with status 0
2021/08/12 12:22:42 socat[5435] N childdied(): handling signal 17
```

My netcat version is not the issue. Netcat is just an example application I am using to test this, and I can see this problem in packet dumps too.

Comment: Does this also occur with TCP? Do you have any NAT rules in iptables or nft?

Comment: It also occurs with TCP (although it's slightly different); I've updated my question. I do not have any NAT rules in iptables and I'm not using nft.

Comment: Tried your commands, and I cannot reproduce this behavior. Can you provide an output of `netstat -utn`?

Comment: You are right, I can't reproduce this issue on a fresh Ubuntu. I've updated the post with the netstat output

Comment: @Joba, sorry, just realised that it should be `netstat -aun` to include listening sockets and not include tcp sockets. Could you please update?

Comment: I have updated the post. I excluded everything that didn't look relevant (so that's the output of `netstat -aun | grep 2345`)

Comment: OK, I tried on a fresh Debian 10 installation, still cannot reproduce this behavior (socat version 1.7.3.2 on Debian 4.19.181-1, release 4.19.0-16-amd64). Can you recheck those commands on your Debian installation, preferably by copy-pasting those commands to eliminate human-factor?

Comment: BTW I had to run `socat` with `sudo`, otherwise it complains with "operation not permitted". Do you run `socat` with or without `sudo`?

Comment: Added a longer edit. I can confim it doesn't happen on a fresh Debian, and using `sudo` and copy pasting commands doesn't change anything for me. Reinstalling Debian isn't an option right now and I suspect it might be related to the Debian image my server host is using anyway.

Comment: Do you have any rules in your firewall on this machine?

Comment: There are a bunch of docker related once for specific ports that shouldn't matter. The only ones that are remotely relevant are now added to the question

Comment: It  would  be more helpful if you provide full configurations. Since we have strange behavior here, which could not be reproduced, it's very likely that the cause is misconfiguration  somewhere in an unexpected place. So every detail could matter. For example, are you absolutely sure that those docker related firewall rules do not do some strange address translation or affect the traffic on some other way resulting this problem?

Comment: I added the rest

Comment: Could you please post _all_ your firewall rules (from `iptables-save` or _at least_ `iptables -t nat -S; iptables -t mangle -S`) in addition to just the filter table?

Comment: Sorry, I was under the impression, that `iptables -S` did just that. I've updated the post with the output of `iptables-save`

Comment: @Joba so have you tried replacing "receiving" `nc` command with `socat` as I suggested?

Comment: What is your network config, i.e. `ip a`? Looks like you have a plenty of interfaces/bridges, and it is not clear what ip addresses from the iptables output each of them has.

Comment: I've attached the output of `ip a`

Comment: @Joba, hi, are you still interested in resolving this issue?

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have missed the last comment. I've updated my question with the output of the 3 respective `socat` commands.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `lo` interface scope - I think you need to change it from `host` to `global`.

You can do this in `[/etc/network/interfaces][1]` if you're using Debian (need to do `ifdown lo` and `ifup lo` to make it go into effect) or use the `ip addr set dev lo scope global` command (I think).

[Details](https://serverfault.com/questions/63014/ip-address-scope-parameter)

I had to do this to get DNS queries originating from localhost to have the source address set correctly so it could receive replies from a DNS server hosted on localhost, where the DNS server was also accessible on other interfaces.

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix it. Changing the scope of `lo` had no effect (according to `ip addr`). Creating a new interface with a global scope is possible, but the problem persists.

The fresh Debian installation that doesn't have this problem also has `lo` with scope `host`, so setting it to `global` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: `lo` interface is host loopback and should never be global. Wouldn't change the scope myself.

Comment: @JariTurkia It was the only way I could get BIND on my PC-based router to send DNS queries originating from itself (127.0.0.1) to actually come from 127.0.0.1 as a source IP and not from eth0's IP address which it was doing for some reason I can't fathom--needed because BIND introduced access lists so the source IP had to be correct and I don't want to serve DNS over my WAN interface.  Anyway, worth a shot, sorry it didn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

Since, as you confirm, this behavior could not be reproduced, it's not your misunderstanding or incorrect usage of `socat`. It's  something in your particular setup: either misconfiguration or incorrect diagnostics by `nc`. Here are suggestions for troubleshooting.

I'll be using following terms to reference the commands:

1. Generator, command 1 (I've added the `-q0` so `nc` doesn't "hang"):

   ```
   echo test | nc -u -q0 127.0.0.1 12345
   ```
2. Main command, command 2:

   ```
   socat -T5 UDP4-LISTEN:12345,reuseaddr,fork UDP4:127.0.0.1:23456,bind=127.0.0.2,so-bindtodevice=lo
   ```
3. Receiver, receiving command, command 3:

   ```
   nc -u -l -p 23456 -vv
   ```

### 1. More diagnostics.

Replace the receiver command with one of the following (they are almost equivalent):

```
socat -d -d UDP-RECVFROM:23456,fork -
socat -d -d -T.5 UDP-LISTEN:23456,fork -
socat -d -d UDP-RECV:23456 -
```

Also add `-d -d` to the main command.

This will let you get more info about what's going on.

### 2. Analyze packets.

Use some packet dumper and analyzer (Wireshark, tcpdump) on all interfaces to capture packets and figure out what actual packets are sent.

### 3. Check the packet filter rules.

Besides the packet filter rules you provided there are three more tables to look at:

```
sudo iptables -S -t nat
sudo iptables -S -t mangle
sudo iptables -S -t raw
```

### 4. Netcat version

What's the version of `nc`? Maybe it is buggy? Also it turns out that there are two netcats: traditional and OpenBSD version.

```
$ nc -h 2>&1 | head -n 1
[v1.10-41.1]
```

### Proper behavior (for reference)

Command 1:

```
$ echo test | nc -u -q0 127.0.0.1 12345
$
```

Command 2:

```
$ sudo socat -T5 -d -d UDP4-LISTEN:12345,reuseaddr,fork UDP4:127.0.0.1:23456,bind=127.0.0.2,so-bindtodevice=lo
2021/07/23 01:49:48 socat[4617] N listening on UDP AF=2 0.0.0.0:12345
2021/07/23 01:51:12 socat[4617] N accepting UDP connection from AF=2 127.0.0.1:59877
2021/07/23 01:51:12 socat[4617] N forked off child process 4622
2021/07/23 01:51:12 socat[4617] N listening on UDP AF=2 0.0.0.0:12345
2021/07/23 01:51:12 socat[4622] N opening connection to AF=2 127.0.0.1:23456
2021/07/23 01:51:12 socat[4622] N successfully connected from local address AF=2 127.0.0.2:36338
2021/07/23 01:51:12 socat[4622] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [5,5] and [6,6]
2021/07/23 01:51:17 socat[4622] N inactivity timeout triggered
2021/07/23 01:51:17 socat[4622] N exiting with status 0
2021/07/23 01:51:17 socat[4617] N childdied(): handling signal 17
```

Command 3:

```
vagrant@packer-debian-10-amd64:~$ socat -d -d UDP-RECVFROM:23456,fork -
2021/07/23 01:50:54 socat[4619] N receiving on AF=2 0.0.0.0:23456
2021/07/23 01:51:12 socat[4619] N receiving packet from AF=2 127.0.0.2:36338
2021/07/23 01:51:12 socat[4619] N forked off child process 4623
2021/07/23 01:51:12 socat[4623] N reading from and writing to stdio
2021/07/23 01:51:12 socat[4623] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [5,5] and [0,1]
2021/07/23 01:51:12 socat[4623] N received packet with 5 bytes from AF=2 127.0.0.2:36338
2021/07/23 01:51:12 socat[4619] N receiving on AF=2 0.0.0.0:23456
test
2021/07/23 01:51:12 socat[4623] N socket 1 (fd 5) is at EOF
2021/07/23 01:51:13 socat[4623] N exiting with status 0
2021/07/23 01:51:13 socat[4619] N receiving on AF=2 0.0.0.0:23456
```

### Side notes.

1. I think the `so-bindtodevice=lo` option in the main command is not necessary, since you are already binding to ip address with `bind=127.0.0.2`.
2. If your task is not about learning every bit of `socat` behavior, but more about getting things done (like forwarding specific udp traffic between subnets), I suggest you to use packet filter and its NAT capabilities for this task. It would be proper way to do that, because `socat` works on application level (L7), and packet filter works on the network level (L3).

Comment: Using the other `socat` commands gives me the same output you see, but with my external ip instead of `127.0.0.2`. tcpdump confirms, that the source ip is not `127.0.0.2`.

Comment: Also, I'm awarding the bounty to this question. Even though it didn't fix my problem, you did a lot to try to figure this out. Thank you.

Comment: But  still what are the outputs of the main `socat` (with `-d -d` added) and the receiving `socat`. Comparing those can be interesting.